# JunitTestClass Is Failing for My JAVA Class

Tags: junit

I am new to JUNIT and never worked on this. Below is my JAVA Class and JUNIT

**************** JAVA CLASS ******************

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.HttpConstants;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import test.core.constants.Constants;
import test.core.data.AgenciesCommunityModel;
import test.core.service.ContentFragmentService;
import test.core.service.EntityRelationUpdateService;
import test.core.service.ServletResponse;
import test.core.util.ApiUtility;

@Component(service = Servlet.class, property = { "sling.servlet.methods=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_POST,
        "sling.servlet.paths=" + "/bin/brgAgencies",
        // "sling.auth.requirements=" + "-/system/sling/login"
})
public class AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet.class);

    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Reference
    private transient ContentFragmentService contentFragmentService;

    @Reference
    private transient EntityRelationUpdateService updateRelationService;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ApiUtility.fetchFragmentResponse(contentFragmentService, request, response, Constants.AGENCY_COMMUNITY_FRAGMENT,Constants.AGENCY, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String type = request.getParameter(Constants.TYPE) != null ? request.getParameter(Constants.TYPE) : "";
        logger.info("type outside IF Statement !type.isEmpty() ======= " + type);   
        ServletResponse serviceResponse;
        
        AgenciesCommunityModel agenciesCommunityModel = gson.fromJson(request.getReader(),AgenciesCommunityModel.class);//coming value here

        boolean publishStatus = ApiUtility.isPublished(request.getResourceResolver(),agenciesCommunityModel.getPath());
        logger.info("publishStatus outside IF Statement !type.isEmpty() ======= " + publishStatus);     
        if (!type.isEmpty() && type.equals(Constants.VERIFY)) {
            //AgenciesCommunityModel agenciesCommunityModel = gson.fromJson(request.getReader(),AgenciesCommunityModel.class);//coming NULL value here
            logger.info("publishStatus INSIDE agenciesCommunity ======= " + publishStatus);
            if (publishStatus == true) {
                ApiUtility.verifyContentFromMDS(updateRelationService, request, response, Constants.COMMUNITIES);
            }
        } 
        else {
            //AgenciesCommunityModel agenciesCommunityModel = gson.fromJson(request.getReader(),AgenciesCommunityModel.class);
            if (agenciesCommunityModel.getPath().equals("/")) {
                String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");
                String[] parts = referer.split(".html");
                if (parts.length > 1) {
                    String part = parts[1];
                    String nodePath = part.substring(0, part.lastIndexOf(Constants.SLASH));
                    agenciesCommunityModel.setPath(nodePath + Constants.SLASH);
                }
            }
            serviceResponse = contentFragmentService.createNewAgenciesCommunity(agenciesCommunityModel);
            ApiUtility.populateResponseObject(response, serviceResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

******************************* JUNIT ******************************

```java
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.LoginException;
import org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.ResourceResolverType;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import test.core.TestUtils;
import test.core.constants.Constants;
import test.core.data.AgenciesCommunityModel;
import test.core.service.ContentFragmentService;
import test.core.service.EntityRelationUpdateServiceImpl;
import test.core.service.ServletResponse;
import io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit5.AemContext;
import io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit5.AemContextExtension;

@ExtendWith({AemContextExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
public class AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServletTest {
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet.class);

    @Rule
    private final AemContext context = new AemContext(ResourceResolverType.JCR_MOCK);

    @Mock
    ContentFragmentService agenciesService;
    
    @Mock
    EntityRelationUpdateServiceImpl updateService;

    @InjectMocks
    private AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet agenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet = new AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet();

    private final String COMMUNITY_PATH = "/content/dam/test/test1/test";

    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws RepositoryException, URISyntaxException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        context.resourceResolver();
        String json = gson.toJson(TestUtils.getMockBRGCommunityModel("/content/dam/test/test1/test"));
        context.request().setContent(json.getBytes());
    }

    @Test
    void doPostShouldReturn204() throws ServletException, IOException {
        when(agenciesService.createNewAgenciesCommunity(any(AgenciesCommunityModel.class))).thenReturn(TestUtils.getExpectedServletResponse(ServletResponse.ServletResponseType.RES_204));
        agenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet.doPost(context.request(), context.response());
        Assert.assertEquals("Response code should match", 204, context.response().getStatus());
    }

    
    @Test
    void doPostUpdateRelationShouldReturn200() throws IOException, LoginException {
        when(updateService.updateEntityData(context.request(), COMMUNITY_PATH, Constants.COMMUNITIES)).thenReturn(TestUtils.getExpectedServletResponse(ServletResponse.ServletResponseType.RES_200));
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(Constants.PATH, COMMUNITY_PATH);
        params.put(Constants.TYPE, Constants.VERIFY);
        context.request().setParameterMap(params);
        agenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet.doPost(context.request(), context.response());

        Assert.assertEquals("Response code should match", 200, context.response().getStatus());
    }
    
    @Test
    void doPostUpdateRelationShouldThrowExceptionReturn500() throws IOException, LoginException {
        when(updateService.updateEntityData(context.request(), COMMUNITY_PATH, Constants.COMMUNITIES)).thenReturn(TestUtils.getExpectedServletResponse(ServletResponse.ServletResponseType.RES_500));
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(Constants.PATH, COMMUNITY_PATH);
        params.put(Constants.TYPE, Constants.VERIFY);
        context.request().setParameterMap(params);
        //agenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet.doPost();
        agenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet.doPost(context.request(), context.response());

        Assert.assertEquals("Response code should match", 500, context.response().getStatus());
    }

}
```

all my post method in JUNIT is not working.

I am getting nullpointer error like below.

Errors:

[ERROR]   AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServletTest.doPostShouldReturn400:72 » NullPointer

[ERROR]   AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServletTest.doPostShouldReturn500:79 » NullPointer

[ERROR]   AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServletTest.doPostUpdateRelationShouldReturn200:93 » NullPointer

[ERROR]   AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServletTest.doPostUpdateRelationShouldThrowExceptionReturn500:107 » NullPointer

Comment: Could you: 1. prepare minimal example - you have 4 tests failing, some of which are not included in your listing. 2. post entire stack trace, ideally with [Verbose NullPointerException messages](https://www.baeldung.com/java-14-nullpointerexception)

Comment: I have updated my question in more clarity in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75589861/apiutilituy-ispublished-junit

Comment: Usually you should [edit] your question instead of posting a new one that may get closed as a duplicate. Please see [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apiUtilituy.isPublished Junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75589861/apiutilituy-ispublished-junit)