# apiUtilituy.isPublished Junit

Tags: junit, junit5, spring-test

I have one ApiUtility Java Class with Boolean method and want to write the JUNIT for this.

I am trying like below.

My Java Class is bleow.

```java
public static boolean isPublished(ResourceResolver resourceResolver, String path) {
   logger.info("Inside isPublished");
   Resource resource = resourceResolver.getResource(path);
   logger.info("Inside isPublished resource ===== "+ resource);
   Resource jcrResource = resource.getChild(Constants.JCR_CONTENT_NODE);
   if (jcrResource != null) {
      return jcrResource.getValueMap().get(Constants.CQ_LAST_REPLICATION_ACTION, "").equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTIVATE);
   }
   return false;
   
}
```

I am trying to write My JUNIT Class like below. But Not able to.

```java
 
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.LoginException;
import org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.ResourceResolverType;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import ai.test.core.TestUtils;
import ai.test.core.constants.Constants;
import ai.test.core.service.ContentFragmentService;
import ai.test.core.service.EntityRelationUpdateServiceImpl;
import ai.test.core.service.ServletResponse;
import io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit5.AemContext;
import io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit5.AemContextExtension;

@ExtendWith({AemContextExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
public class AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServletTest {
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Rule
    private final AemContext context = new AemContext(ResourceResolverType.JCR_MOCK);

    @Mock
    ContentFragmentService agenciesService;
    
    @Mock
    EntityRelationUpdateServiceImpl updateService;

    @InjectMocks
    private AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet agenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet = new AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet();

    private final String COMMUNITY_PATH = "/content/dam/content-admin/global/communities/agency/test";
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws RepositoryException, URISyntaxException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        context.resourceResolver();
        String json = gson.toJson(TestUtils.getMockBRGCommunityModel("/content/dam/content-admin/global/communities/agency/test"));
        context.request().setContent(json.getBytes());
    }

    @Test
    void doPostUpdateRelationShouldReturn200() throws IOException, LoginException {
        when(updateService.updateEntityData(context.request(), COMMUNITY_PATH, Constants.COMMUNITIES)).thenReturn(TestUtils.getExpectedServletResponse(ServletResponse.ServletResponseType.RES_200));
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(Constants.PATH, COMMUNITY_PATH);
        params.put(Constants.TYPE, Constants.VERIFY);
        context.request().setParameterMap(params);
        agenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet.doPost(context.request(), context.response());

        Assert.assertEquals("Response code should match", 200, context.response().getStatus());
    }
    
    @Test
    void doPostUpdateRelationShouldThrowExceptionReturn500() throws IOException, LoginException {
        when(updateService.updateEntityData(context.request(), COMMUNITY_PATH, Constants.COMMUNITIES)).thenReturn(TestUtils.getExpectedServletResponse(ServletResponse.ServletResponseType.RES_500));
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(Constants.PATH, COMMUNITY_PATH);
        params.put(Constants.TYPE, Constants.VERIFY);
        context.request().setParameterMap(params);
        agenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServlet.doPost(context.request(), context.response());

        Assert.assertEquals("Response code should match", 500, context.response().getStatus());
    }

}
```

But I am getting null pointer exception like below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ai.marcel.contentadmin.core.util.ApiUtility.isPublished(ApiUtility.java:1128)
    at ai.marcel.contentadmin.core.servlets.AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServletTest.doPostUpdateRelationShouldReturn200(AgenciesCommunityNodeAmangerServletTest.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

My servlet JAVA Class is below

```java
@Override
protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
   
   String type = request.getParameter(Constants.TYPE) != null ? request.getParameter(Constants.TYPE) : "";
   logger.info("type outside IF Statement !type.isEmpty() ======= " + type);  
   
   //AgenciesCommunityModel agenciesCommunityModel = gson.fromJson(request.getReader(),AgenciesCommunityModel.class);//coming value here
   
   if (!type.isEmpty() && type.equals(Constants.VERIFY)) {
      logger.info("type INSIDE IF Statement !type.isEmpty() ======= " + type);
      boolean publishStatus = ApiUtility.isPublished(request.getResourceResolver(),request.getPathInfo());
      logger.info("publishStatus INSIDE agenciesCommunity ======= " + publishStatus);
      if (publishStatus == true) {
         ApiUtility.verifyContentFromMDS(updateRelationService, request, response, Constants.COMMUNITIES);
      }
   }
```

AS I have never worked on JUNIT, can anybody please help me here.

I am writing a JUNIt test class but no success.

Answer (score 0):

please provide also the resource mock, it seems that the resource resolver is returning null.

Comment: @Lesiak , Also I have set below mock and still getting error. Mockito.when(context.request().getResourceResolver()).thenReturn(resourceResolver);

Answer (score 0):

You never arrive to method under test as you are setting up your mocks incorrectly.

The problem is in:

```java
when(ApiUtility.isPublished(resourceResolver, COMMUNITY_PATH)).thenReturn(true);
```

This is incorrect way to stub a static method.
See [Mocking static methods](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks) in Mockito docs for a correct way.

Normally, Mockito reports incorrect stubbing attempts like:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

You don't receive this message as you have a NPE exception one step before - you call real implementation of `isPublished` and NPE is thrown from within it.

NPE is thrown as you haven't stubbed any methods on `resourceResolver`.

Comment: @Nistor, I have updated Mock also. Thanks a lot for your help.